# Convergence of a sequence of continuable Dirichlet series

Tags: dirichlet-series

Let's say $f$ is a Dirichlet series which converges on the half-plane $\text{Re }s>\sigma$ to a function $f(s)$. Suppose further that $f(s)$ admits an analytic continuation to an entire function, together with the standard sort of functional equation.  Let $g_n$ be a sequence of Dirichlet series, also convergent on $\text{Re }s>\sigma$, which each admit an analytic continuation and functional equation, though their precise FEs may vary.  We assume that $g_n$ converges to $f$ in the following sense:  for every $m>0$ there exists an $N$ for which the series $g_n$ and $f$ match on every term up to the $m$th, for all $n>N$.  Note this implies that $g_n(s)$ converges to $f(s)$ for every $\text{Re }s>\sigma$.

Can it be said that $g_n(s)$ converges to $f(s)$ for any $s$ outside the domain of convergence?

Perhaps that's too much to hope for, and you can't even expect that $g_n(s)$ converges to $f(s)$ even for the point $s=\sigma$.  I'd certainly be interested in a counterexample which does this!

Comment: If one imposes some conditions on the functional equations of the g_n's (in particular, bounding the conductors to avoid FC's counterexample) then the answer could potentially become "yes."  

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer is a community wiki version of a comment above by FC which answered the question.)

For any integer M, there exists a prime p such that chi_p(n) = (n/p) = 1 for all n = 1...M. This means that the Dirichlet series L(s,V chi_p) (for any representation V) "converges" in your sense to L(s,V). but they do not converge at s = 0. If V is trivial, then we are comparing zeta(0) = -1/2 with L(0,chi_p) which grows without bound by Brauer-Siegel. I think in this class of examples one does get convergence at the critical point.

Comment: The question requires f(s) to be entire, which is excluded if V is trivial -- I've thought of this counterexample already.  Can anything be said if V is nontrivial?  Still, this example hints at a negative answer to the question, since zeta(s) is regular at 0 whereas the f_n(s) do not converge.  So, +1.

Comment: So it does.  *Accept*.